# æøå in csv export

Tags: php, csv, slim

I'm trying to export some data into an CSV file i can download.

if im hitting my API in postman the data looks fine like:

```
Notat,Vare,Type,Størrelse,Tekst,Antal,Pris,Rabatprocent,Totalbeløb,Fakturerbar,"Lever nu",Faktureret,Lagersted,Placering,Lagerstyring
,,,,"Fadol 0,5 - 6 stk. ",4,,"0,00",1000,Checked,0,"0,00",,,Intet
,,,,"Classic 0,5",34,,"0,00",1700,Checked,0,"0,00",,,Intet
,,,,"Classic 0,5 - 6 stk ",3,,"0,00",750,Checked,0,"0,00",,,Intet
,,,,"Grimbergen 0,3",6,,"0,00",240,Checked,0,"0,00",,,Intet
,,,,"Nordic flaske ",0,,"0,00",0,Checked,0,"0,00",,,Intet
,,,,Kildevand,109,,"0,00",2160,Checked,0,"0,00",,,Intet
,,,,"Smirnoff 6 stk",0,,"0,00",0,Checked,0,"0,00",,,Intet
,,,,"Sæson 0,3",2,,"0,00",80,Checked,0,"0,00",,,Intet
,,,,"Sodavand 0,3",5,,"0,00",150,Checked,0,"0,00",,,Intet
,,,,"Sodavand 0,5",102,,"0,00",4040,Checked,0,"0,00",,,Intet
,,,,"Fadøl 0,5",20,,"0,00",1000,Checked,0,"0,00",,,Intet
,,,,"Kop varme drikke",17,,"0,00",255,Checked,0,"0,00",,,Intet
```

But when i open the CSV file after downloading it will show Størrelse as StÃ¸rrelse. Så it works fine in postman but not in the actual CSV file. someone can point me in the right direction for where my problem is?

Here is my code that creates the export:

```
//Open file pointer.        
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        //Loop through the associative array.
        foreach($sortedData as $row){
            //Write the row to the CSV file.

            fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }

        //Finally, close the file pointer.
        fclose($fp);

        $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="file.csv"');

        $stream = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');      

        return $response->withBody(new \Slim\Http\Stream($stream));
```

Comment: You are opening CSV via Excel? It's using non-UTF8 encoding. Open CSV with simple text editor. If you still see these wrong symbols, then it means your strings are not UTF8 passed in, and converting to output of UTF8 ruins it. Try encoding it with WINDOWS-1252 encoding.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by *"open the CSV file after downloading"*. Which tool do you use to open the CSV file? Is it Excel, LibreOffice Calc or something else?

Comment: Depending on the tool, you need to "open" the CSV file in a different way. For example, here are instructions for Excel: https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-import-csv-file-uses-utf-8-character-encoding-0

Comment: By the way, Excel is really bad on CSV files processing ;)

Comment: @Justinas Yes i open via excel

Comment: @Justinas you are right, it looks correctly with notepad++ . does that mean my excel setup is wrong but code is fine?

Comment: @SonnyHansen Yes. Or your code is not compatible with Excel

Answer (score 0):

depends on encoding type. I got similar issue with csv file.I converted the row to "ISO-8859-1" ( for german characters) .

```
 iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text), "ISO-8859-1", $text);
```